# can I control instanced mesh length or depth based on edge length of base mesh along with normal in geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to control the **length** or **depth** of instanced mesh(cylinder in this case) according to  base mesh edge length. In the following picture I converted the base mesh into curve to get the instance point along with normal. As you can see the length is not accurate, either smaller or bigger. I don't know how to get the face length and make it control instanced mesh length or depth. Is it possible using current geometry nodes?
or my process is wrong?

here is the blend file.
[image]

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file?

Comment: provided @Chris

Comment: Hello, could you add a screenshot of how it should look like ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although i am not sure what you want to have...you can use this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Comment: Hello chris, Thanks for your answer and it worked. Can I make it procedurally? I mean as those instanced object overlap I need to use boolean mesh to remove overlap region which cost huge computation for bigger object.

Comment: @dipdeb: if my answer helped, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you. If you have further/other question, please open a new question. I didn't quite understand your comment: could you please open a new question and maybe link this one to it and tell a bit more detailed what you want to have? Thank you.